# Optimize / solve equation for unknown exponent

Tags: r

I have dataframe with the following variables: **a** and **b** as predictors and **c** as outcome. My formula is:
**c = (a^x) / (a^x + b^x)**
How to solve for **x**?

Example data:

```
dat <- data.frame(a = runif(5, 1, 100), b = runif(5, 10, 20), c = runif(5, 0, 1))
```

Reply to comment:

> What is your expected output? A single x-value from least squares fitting, or a column **x**?

The whole column (sum of all row errors). I want to minimize the error for every row.

Comment: Show us some data.

Comment: > dataset = data.frame(a = runif(5, 1, 100), b = runif(5, 10, 20), c = runif(5, 0, 1)) 
> dataset 
         a        b          c
1 44.60262 14.59877 0.81809363
2 72.71362 13.53185 0.01232237
3 20.65488 14.00915 0.34687608
4 20.95614 13.45155 0.84053839
5 43.55494 10.79428 0.64728379

Comment: Sorry, the whole column (sum of all row errors). I want to minimize the error for every row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code

```
library(minpack.lm)

dataset = data.frame(a = runif(5, 1, 100), b = runif(5, 10, 20), c = runif(5, 0, 1)) 

fun <- as.formula(c ~ a^x/(a^x + b^x))

#Fitting model using minpack.lm package
nls.out1 <- nlsLM(fun, 
                  data = dataset,
                  start=list(x=1),
                  algorithm = "LM",
                  control = nls.lm.control(maxiter = 500))

summary(nls.out1)
```